# Inverse_transform function giving me grief with LSTM

Tags: python, numpy, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am having an issue with **inverse_transform()** function returning the error “**ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (693,1) doesn’t match the broadcast shape (693,11)**”

I am attempting to use LSTM to a series of 11 features (including the closing price) to predict a stock price. I am able to fetch the data and create a dataframe with the 11 features + a timestamp as an index. I get to the point where I use MinMaxScaler to normalize the features (0,1). At this point I test the shapes for the train and test shapes. They are (697,11) and (340,11), respectively. I believe this is what I want for both sets.

I define trainX, trainY using the function create-dataset previously defined. The goal of the function is to transform the time series data into a format suitable for training.

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1): 
    dataX, dataY = [], [] 
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1): 
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0] 
        dataX.append(a) 
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0]) 
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY).reshape(-1, 1)
```

I do the same for TrainY and TestY.

TrainX, TestX Shapes: (693, 3) (340, 3)
TrainY, TestY Shapes: (693, 1), (340,3)

Notice that the shape of the dataframe has changed when we convert X and Y to a numpy array. I guess this is expected, right? In the function look_back = 3. What is confusing to me is that in the df the second number in the shape (693, 11), but in the array the second number in the shape refers to the number of periods I look back. So, I’m not clear if the array captures the features.

The LSTM model runs find, but the script fails when I try to get the original values back using inverse_transform. I receive the dreaded “ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (693,1) doesn’t match the broadcast shape (693,11)” message and I don’t know how to resolve it.

```
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX) 
testPredict = model.predict(testX) 
trainY = np.squeeze(trainY) 
testY = np.squeeze(testY)  
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)                       
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY]) 
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict) 
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Here is more of the code:

```
results = {}
with open('stocks.txt', 'r') as file:
    symbols = [line.strip() for line in file]

start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2023-10-31'
interval = '1'  

# %%
# Loop through each symbol and retrieve data
for symbol in symbols:
    # Construct the full URL with API key and date parameters
    endpoint = f'/v2/aggs/ticker/{symbol}/range/{interval}/day/{start_date}/{end_date}'
    url = f'{BASE_URL}{endpoint}?apiKey={API_KEY}'

    try:
        # Send a GET request to the API
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the JSON response
            data = response.json()

            # Convert 't' to DataFrame for easier manipulation and set it as the DataFrame index
            df = pd.DataFrame(data['results'])            
            df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], unit='ms')
            df.set_index('t', inplace=True) #Setting to the True method modifies the original df directly instead of returning a new df
                        
            df['20DMA'] = df['c'].rolling(window=20).mean()
            df['20DSTD'] = df['c'].rolling(window=20).std()
            df['UpperBand'] = df['20DMA'] + (df['20DSTD'] * 2)
            df['LowerBand'] = df['20DMA'] - (df['20DSTD'] * 2)
            results[symbol] = df
            print(df.to_string(index=True))

        else:
            print(f"Error for symbol {symbol}: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred for symbol {symbol}: {e}")


look_back = 3
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY).reshape(-1, 1) #Reshape dataY to be 2D #update line in 20231116-Code-d. 


for symbol, dataframe in results.items():
    
    data = dataframe[['c', 'v', 'vw', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'n', '20DMA', '20DSTD', 'UpperBand', 'LowerBand']].values
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(data)    
    num_fields = dataset.shape[1]  
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
    trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
    testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back) 
      
    # Reshape the input to be [samples, time steps, features]
    trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
    testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
    print(trainX.shape, testX.shape) 
    
    # Create and fit the LSTM network
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1, look_back), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back))) 
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2, validation_data=(testX, testY))
    trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
    testPredict = model.predict(testX)
    trainY = np.squeeze(trainY)
    testY = np.squeeze(testY)
    trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)                                 
    trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])                                           
    testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)                                   
    testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
    
    # Calculate root mean squared error (RMSE) for the training and testing data.
    trainScore = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
    print(f'{symbol} Train Score: {trainScore:.2f} RMSE')
    testScore = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
    print(f'{symbol} Test Score: {testScore:.2f} RMSE')

    
trainY = np.squeeze(trainY)
testY = np.squeeze(testY)

def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=hp.Int('layer 1', min_value=32, max_value=128, step=32), input_shape=(1, look_back), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(units=hp.Int('layer 2', min_value=32, max_value=128, step=32), input_shape=(1, look_back)))
    # hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4,])
    model.add(Dense(1))                             
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

I've tried playing around with the shape of array but I'm clearly out of my depth here.

Comment: You've fit the `MinMaxScaler` to the whole dataset, and then tried to use that scaler on your prediction which is a single value (thus the 11 versus 1 in the error message). Split your data into X and Y first, then create separate scalers for X and Y. Then use the Y scaler for the inverse transform. Note with this approach you'll have to use `reshape` or `expand_dims` on the Y data since the scaler needs a 2-dimensional array